# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application , and i have the following method to upload a json object to a 3rd part application. where i want to set the url header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                {
                    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var encodedJson = WebUtility.UrlEncode(data);
                    crudoutput = wc.UploadValues(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + encodedJson);
                }
```

but the above is raising the following error :-

> cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'
>
> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(System.Uri,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)' has some invalid
>   arguments

so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is pretty clear. `UploadValues` takes a `NameValueCollection` not a string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx

You code should be

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();

nvc.Add("INPUT_DATA", encodedJson);

crudoutput = wc.UploadValues(uri, nvc);
```

## Update

You might try `UploadString` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx

```
crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + encodedJson);
```

Comment: not sure why you are using this myNameValueCollection.Add("INPUT_DATA",encodedJson) ..now in my case the json should start with "INPUT_DATA=" so i need to do a concatitation between "INPUT_DATA=" and encodedJson ,, as shown inside my original code..

Comment: Then try `UploadString` instead. You asked about why you were getting the error, which all these answers fix

Comment: but i wanted to use UploadValues since i want to specify the content type header as application/x-www-form-urlencoded ,, as i know i can not do so using UploadString ??

Comment: guess you'll have to make a pull request to the .Net library then so they can change it for you. As the error states, you can't pass a string type to `UploadValues`

Comment: i did understand your point "guess you'll have to make a pull request to the .Net library then so they can change it for you" ??

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a new `NameValueCollection` and pass it to `UploadValues`:

```
crudoutput = wc.UploadValues(uri, new NameValueCollection()
{
    { "INPUT_DATA", encodedJson }
});
```

Comment: but i need the "INPUT_DATA" & encodedJson to be concatenated together ,, as shown inside my original code ..

Answer (score 3):

WebClient   `UploadValues` method is expecting an `NameValueCollection` instead of `string` as parameter

So you can try this :-

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
     {
         string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
         Uri uri = new Uri(url);       
         wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

         var encodedJson = WebUtility.UrlEncode(data);

         NameValueCollection myNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
         myNameValueCollection.Add("INPUT_DATA",encodedJson);
         crudoutput = wc.UploadValues(uri, myNameValueCollection);
     }
```

Comment: not sure why you are using this myNameValueCollection.Add("INPUT_DATA",encodedJson) ..now in my case the json should start with "INPUT_DATA=" so i need to do a concatitation between "INPUT_DATA=" and encodedJson ,, as shown inside my original code..

Comment: but if you append it like that your json become invalid right? we assumed Input_data is the property name for your content body of post method or the parameter of the calling method. If you really need that, before encoding add - data = data + "INPUT_DATA="

Comment: now the json format should start with INPUT_DATA= .. then i will add my serialized data to it ...